# Howto use parameters in a function or alias in .bashrc on ubuntu?

Tags: bash

For example this does not work:

```
man(){ man -H "$1" & }
```

But I need the parameter, because I want the command to end with an ampersand.

This doesn't work as well:

```
man(){ firefox & man -H }
```

I don't want firefox to close if the firefox process is started by man and man is terminated.

Comment: If you hadn't deleted your prior question, I would have finished extending my answer there.

Comment: BTW, expounding on "does not work" is generally a good idea. What *does* it do? How do you know it doesn't work? Have you run `type man` to ensure that it's actually defined in your current shell instance? Etc.

Comment: BTW, what follows `-H` is supposed to be the name of your browser. I assume you'd want `man() { man -H /path/to/firefox "$@" & }`, or such, instead.

Comment: and even then, that won't have any effect unless the man page you want is actually in HTML format, so I'm not sure why running `man -H ...anything... &` is ever a thing you'd actually want to do.

Comment: Also? Use `set -x` to make your shell log what it's doing to stderr (or the file descriptor pointed at with `BASH_XTRACEFD` on 4.x, if you want to redirect it to a log file -- which is actually a good idea, if `man` is being invoked). If you think it's not actually running the function, put that command first, and see if that's true.

Comment: ...that is, `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>my.log && set -x` -- if you're on bash 4.1 or newer, any subsequent commands will be in `my.log`, including things they (functions they invoke, etc) call.

Comment: Where do you get `firefox & man -H` from? That's not what I suggested. Please follow the steps above to generate a log that shows you what your shell is *actually* doing -- and, if that log shows that the function given in my answer does what it's supposed to (starting a copy of `man` in the background, with a `-H` argument prepended to the set of arguments explicitly passed to the user), consider accepting my answer.

Comment: ...alternately, if you're on a version of bash too early for the `BASH_XTRACEFD` trick to work, follow up with details on the version you're running and I'll provide an alternative -- but it's impossible to debug without feedback on the code I'm actually giving you (as opposed to other code I haven't at any point suggested).

Comment: BTW, if your interest is in reading man pages in a web browser, you might consider using `man2html` to do a bulk conversion. That said, a question focused on reading man pages in a web browser arguably belongs in an entirely different question than one about function declaration and invocation syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter isn't a problem. The *recursion* is the (most severe immediate) problem.

When you have a function named `man` call `man`, it calls itself. You're starting an unbounded set of background shells. Using `command` will prevent that recursion, as it bypasses function lookup.

One change I *would* suggest making with respect to parameter-passing is using `"$@"`, so the full set of parameters is passed through, not only the first one:

```
man() { command man -H "$@" & }
```

---

Note, by the way, that at least for the BSD implementation used by Apple, `man -H` expects the name of a program that can convert HTML to text to be the immediate following argument. If you think that, for instance, `man -H bash &` will start the bash man page in a web browser in the background... well, that may be the case on your platform, but it's not universally true.